# WAMP is not responding to external requests

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

> **Installed WAMPServer**
>
> Version : 3.0.4
>   OS type : 64 bit
>   Apache  : 2.4.18
>   PHP     : 5.6.19 / 7.0.4 (5.6.19 checked)
>   MySQL    : 5.7.11

I've tried to look at the older overflow questions and answers and tried to do along as they said, however, I still do not have any connection to the wampserver.

## What I've done to test

1. Use localhost on the host laptop to check if wampserver is operational 
   [SUCCESS]
2. Use my IP on host to check if wampserver is operational [SUCCESS]
3. Use my IP on other devices on the network in attempt to access a php file of the server in a directory. [FAILED]
4. Use other devices to on the network to ping my host [Request timed out x4]
5. Use tracert command as an alternative to 4 [Request timed out]

## What I've done to the server

1. Modification to httpd.conf

   Listen 12.34.56.78:80//commented
   Listen 0.0.0.0:80
   Listen [::0]:80

   Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support//commented
   miscellaneous for LOAD MODULE

   ServerName localhost:80

   Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
   explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
    blocks below.

> ```
> Directory//This directory tag has no reference to server
>     AllowOverride All
>     Require all granted
> Directory
>
> DocumentRoot "E:/Server/wamp64/www" 
> Directory "E:/Server/wamp64/www/"
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
>     AllowOverride All 
>     # onlineoffline tag - don't remove
>     Require all granted 
> Directory
> ```

## What I've done to the host laptop

1. Fresh installation of WAMP
2. Backup original httpd.conf
3. Edited httpd.conf (Refer above)
4. [FAILED]Added rule for port 80 to enable all - Deleted
5. Disable all rules for inbound for port 80
6. Look for rules in outbound for port 80 [NONE]

All of the steps I've described does not work at all. Has no experience in firewall configuration and WAMP configuration. And no virtual hosts except localhost

P/S: The example link I tried testing was 1.1.1.1/testPHP/testPHP.php. The host is Win10 while the device on the similar network tested was XP. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No connection is as in "Connection timed out" message displayed on the browser.

Comment: This might help you , go through all the answers , anyone might help you . http://superuser.com/questions/432794/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-my-wamp-server

Comment: "My IP" is totally wrong. Every interface has its own IP and can have even several IPs. Are you talking about a public IP?

Comment: Uninstall WAMPserver. Then manually delete the `\wamp\` folder and all subfolders, Install WAMPServer again and change NOTHING. Then read this post on [how to create a Virtul Host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: @DanFromGermany not the public IP. Public is 1.9.xxx.xxx, the IP I used is 192.168.xxx.xxx

Comment: @RiggsFolly I had uninstalled the wampserver once, it deleted everything except www did you mean the www?

Comment: No delete the complete `C:/wamp` folder or whatever drive you installed it on

Comment: @RajaGopal cited that link as one of the problem in the answer below. Tried port forwarding didn't seem to work and it caused my laptop to have no internet connection while connected to the router (may have done wrong somewhere on static IP, was following guide to on that)

Comment: @RiggsFolly for some reason, the vhost set up using the guide does not work even. It is present in localhost but the browser gives can't reach this page error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Win 10 apparently had this setting I have had forgotten about - Make this PC discoverable (OFF)

I turned it off in the heydays of using Win 10 because of privacy concerns. Now it can be accessed. The next step is to figure out the forbidden access.

## Edit

The culprit for this post is the Windows 10 OS Settings. In order for all the settings to work (Assuming the person has done all the tinkering with httpd.conf and firewall and/or router), the PC hosting the server must be checked whether is the PC discoverable in the network settings.

*How to make sure it is discovered*

1. Open Network Settings by left clicking the network icon on your taskbar (either lan or WiFi) then click Network Settings right above the bottom most icons.
2. Select Advanced Settings
3. Under the item Make this PC discoverable, there will be a switch button. Make sure the button is turned ON otherwise, left click on that particular button.

Comment: Check now adding the inbound rule, or disable the firewall to test another time.

Comment: Yeah figured it all out, the remaining settings on apache as I had a reinstall for wamp so all are Require Local. Issue sorted. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: So, your problem was a require local directive on Apache?

Comment: No, it was the OS setting the whole time. For Windows 10, regardless of your firewall settings and other settings, you can make your device invisible by using the Win 10 Network control panel "Advanced Settings". In there, you can select whether to turn on or off the setting Make your device discoverable by other devices on this network"

Comment: Ok, i understand. Edit your answer (below this comment), explain it a bit more like Open Network Control Panel / Advanced Settings / Make this PC discoverable (uncheck) and mark it as correct answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The apache configuration seems correct.

**Check this if you're using Wifi on server or client**

Check if the router/AP has enabled something called Wifi Isolation, or Client Isolation.

I looked on a similar router like yours and there it's one option called `Client Isolation` on the Wireless Basic setup of your router. Uncheck it, save and retry.

**Check this on the Windows firewall**

1. Press on your keyboard WindowsKey+R, write control.exe. Press enter
2. Double click on `Windows Firewall`
3. On the left vertical bar select `Advanced Settings`
4. Click `Inbound Rules`
5. On the right pane click `New Rule...`
6. Select `Port` and click `Next button`
7. On the top leave `TCP` option selected. And below select `Specific local ports` and write there `80` or the port your apache uses. Looking to your Listen line on the apache config you should write here 80. Press `Next`
8. Leave selected `Allow the connection` and press `Next`.
9. Select the profiles of the Firewall you want to use for this rule. If you doubt select all. Press `Next`
10. Set a name for the rule, and press `Finish`

Try it another time ;-)

Comment: That was what I did (Written in section "What I've done to the host laptop" item number 4. Still getting time out on this try. Going to restart the laptop to test again.

Comment: Tested, not working. I'm logging into router to tinker around will be back with more info

Comment: I think the issue is with port forwarding as this post suggested http://superuser.com/questions/432794/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-my-wamp-server but I tried to do port forwarding with DLink-2720U to no success. Need help on that

Comment: Ok, I saw the failed text, but I don't know if you did the full test. I edited my answer addind something related to your router, because I think you're using a wifi connection to do the tests.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Dlink-2750U (the router i'm currently connected to) does have this feature in Advanced>Advanced Wireless Setting>User Isolation. It is set to Off

Comment: Did you tried turning off the Firewall? Do it, and ry with Listen 80 in apache instead of Listen 0.0.0.0:80, if it don't works, try with Listen 8000 to change the port where apache it's listening, and change the ServerName to localhost:8000, after restarting apache try browsing with port 8000

Comment: Found the problem. Firewall isn't the culprit is the win 10 setting I have had check the newest answer by me